# Magento Add Discount Pragmatically Showing Error On Paypal Checkout

Tags: php, magento

I am facing one problem when i try to add discount to cart pragmatically i am able to do that but then user try to fill creditcard then paypal shows error :

PayPal Error 10413 ( "  PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details " )

please let me know if anyone know.

Comment: have you created your custom module for that ?

Answer (score 3):

If you adding discount by your custom module then you have to add paypal's event. So in your module's **Config.xml** add new **Event**  for **paypal_prepare_line_items**.

**Like:-**

```
<events>
        <paypal_prepare_line_items>
            <observers>
                <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                    <class>Your_Module_Name/observer</class>
                    <method>updatePaypalTotal</method>
                </paypal_prepare_line_items>
            </observers>
        </paypal_prepare_line_items>
 </events>
```

Now you have to create a observer class in your module and then create a new function **updatePaypalTotal** in that

In **observer.php**

```
public function updatePaypalTotal(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();
    $new_amount = '10'; // This is your Discount amount.
    $cart->updateTotal(Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_DISCOUNT, $new_amount);

    return $this;
}
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: i am using express checkout when i add discount in $new_discount it shows error total not matches with items in cart. its paypal error.

Comment: @SandeepSingh: you need to define paypal event as i showing in this answer....Let me know if you have any query

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. first what i am doing programmatically adding discount in quote ( its like discount on discount - if user using coupon i add more discount in quote then discount become coupon + programmatically discount ) its like discount on discount then user can see discount in quote and after filling all information in checkout user can see discount in review but once user click on place order paypal receive order but order is without new discount old discount with coupon code work but new discount not... i am facing huge problem

Comment: hi i got issue now everything okay ( i am usng http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.com/2011/12/applying-custom-discount-amount-in.html ). now transactions work well but if there's no tax. without tax going well. but when there's tax in quote then it show error " discount not matching with items in quote )

Comment: @SandeepSingh: If you following this post (http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.in/2011/12/applying-custom-discount-amount-in.html) then do one thing. In the config.xml's EVENT node add my CODE(<paypal_prepare_line_items><observers>.....
</observers></paypal_prepare_line_items>) event just after the </sales_quote_collect_totals_after> and then In observer.php put my function just after the setDiscount function..and you will defiantly get success...Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @SandeepSingh:- Remeber that Your discount which you are applying...So Assign that amount IN $new_amount variable which is declared in my function (updatePaypalTotal)

Comment: Hi vishal,

here is link for my observer file its not working with paypal. once we press complete order then paypall transfer amount without discount ( custom discount ) as added.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdd8qddorjn37b6/file.txt

Please take a look.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please check your code is this possible you are adding something extra in in $address-> section

otherwise everything works fine. or please paste your code

Comment: thanks i got i was adding custom discount field in address. thanks a lot